# C, how to store values in a for loop , can it be done without arrays?

Tags: c, store

The assignment asks :

The program must calculate the surface of the house
The user must input the number of rooms he has, and then the program must ask the lenght and witdh of each room. After that the program must show the surface of the house. No formula is provided, but the surface of a room is lenght*width.

The problem with my application is that in the for loop the value of the sum of all lenghts and withs of each room is not remembered. So the output is wrong.
Can it be done without arrays? Because i haven't reached that lesson yet and have alot of other assignments i need to complete. 
Thanks alot.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
int camere,lungime,latime,scamere,i,scamera,scameratotal,scasa,total;


printf("Acest program calculeaza suprafata casei\n");    //this program lists the surface of the house
printf("Cate camere are casa?\n");  // how many rooms do you have?
scanf("%d",&camere);

for(i=0;i<camere;i++)
{

printf("Introduceti lungimea si latimea camerei %d\n",i);   //enter the lenght and width of room %d

scanf("%d %d",&lungime,&latime);


scamera=lungime*latime;    //surface of room %d is lenght*width

printf("Suprafata camerei %d este %d\n",i,scamera);  //states the surface of room %d (1 , 2 or 3 etc.)


total = total + (lungime*latime);   // total that i want the program to remember
scasa=total*camere;                 //surface of the house is total*number of rooms


}

printf("\nSuprafata casei este de %d metri",scasa);  //the surface of the house , bad output , it's not  total(sum of surfaces of each room)*number of rooms
}
```

Comment: Yes, it can be done without arrays.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Thank you all, in the end my formula was off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare another int called total

at the end of your for loop update the total

```
total += lungime*latime;
```

total will have the total floor space at the end after the loop

Comment: Tried it, posted the old version here. It gives bad output.

Comment: ``scasa=total*camere;`` is not needed.  printf at end should print ``total``

Answer (score 1):

```
int total = 0;

for(i=0;i<camere;i++)
{
//ask length
//ask width
total = total + (length * width);
}

display total
```

EDIT :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    int length = 0;
    int width = 0;
    int rooms = 0;
    int total = 0;

    printf("Acest program calculeaza suprafata casei\n");
    printf("Cate camere are casa?\n");
    scanf("%d", &rooms);

    for(int i=0;i<rooms;i++)
    {
        printf("Introduceti lungimea si latimea camerei %d\n",i);
        scanf("%d %d",&length,&width);
        total = total + (length * width);
    }

    printf("Suprafata casei este de %d square meter", total);
}
```

if this doesn't work maybe there is a mistake in the use of scanf but never used it

Comment: Tried it, it gives bad value.

Comment: always assign your values when you declare it, because you never know in which memory space it is stored and if this memory space is empty, and give space to your code declaring 10 variables in one line is the best way to get lost in middle of the logic, also meter * meter = square meter ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code exhibits undefined behaviour as you do calculations with uninitialized variables just before the first `printf`. Here is your code with all the changes explained:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //unwanted header

int main() //use int main
{
    int camere,lungime,latime,scamere,i,scamera,scameratotal=0,scasa; //some unused variables here!

    //scamera=lungime*latime;
    //scameratotal+=scamera; Undefined behaviour here!

    printf("Acest program calculeaza suprafata casei\n");
    printf("Cate camere are casa?\n");
    scanf("%d",&camere);

    for(i=0;i<camere;i++)
    {

       printf("Introduceti lungimea si latimea camerei %d\n",i+1); //room numbers start from 1 not 0
       scanf("%d %d",&lungime,&latime);
       scamera=lungime*latime;
       scameratotal+=scamera; // add each scamera
       printf("Suprafata camerei %d este %d\n",i+1,scamera); //i+1 here too
    }

    //scamera=lungime*latime;
    //scasa=scamera*camere; unwanted lines here!

    printf("Suprafata casei este de %d metri",scameratotal); //i think you need to display total surface area
    return 0; //main returns int
}
```

Comment: Thank you, my formula was off.

Comment: @MichaelWalz , I don't know why,but OperaMini does not do anything when I hit EDIT in this particular answer. Anyway,now I've improved the formatting from my computer.